# How many parallel execution possible using executeOnExecuter?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

In my application I need to provide download functionality for document when user tap on document from list.

So, for multiple active threads AsyncTask come into my mind. But I also noticed that people have not recommended AsyncTask for this kind of operation. Because in this case large no. of thread will get start on tapping of document.

Another reason to don't take AsynTask is that "The modern AsyncTask is limited to 128 concurrent tasks". Means that if you queue up more than 138 tasks before they can complete, your app will crash.

1. Will executeOnExecutor() method solve my purpose or I need to rethink over it?
2. If I start 50 task at same time then all these task run simeltenioulsy by executeOnExecutor()?
3. Concurrent task limit(128) also applicable to executeOnExecutor()?

I expect perfect answer.

Comment: most of questions depend on which exactly executor you will execute it.

Comment: I am going to use AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it is a default executor, on which all asynctasks are done by default. So you don't need to call `executeOnExecutor`, just `execute`, if you want it to be executed on it.

Comment: What should I use in such type of scenario? My moto is  whatever no. of documents. they should download via thread.

Answer (score 1):

> Another reason to don't take AsynTask is that "The modern AsyncTask is limited to 128 concurrent tasks". Means that if you queue up more than 138 tasks before they can complete, your app will crash.

More accurately, `AsyncTask`'s built-in executors use a 128-element work queue to handle requests that are waiting for threads. Note, though, that this limit is not documented and is subject to change.

> Will executeOnExecutor() method solve my purpose

That depends entirely upon what sort of `Executor` that you supply to `executeOnExecutor()`.

> If I start 50 task at same time then all these task run simeltenioulsy by executeOnExecutor()?

No. For starters, your CPU does not have that many cores.

> Concurrent task limit(128) also applicable to executeOnExecutor()?

Only if you set up your `Executor` with that limit. If you use one of the two built-in `AsyncTask` executors (`SERIAL_EXECUTOR`, `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`), then yes, that queue limit should be in place.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Just need to clarify that Will app get crash if asyncTask have 150-200 queued items?

Comment: @RohanPatel: That depends mostly upon what sort of `Executor` that you supply to `executeOnExecutor()`, and secondarily on how much heap space that you have.

Comment: what sort of Executor i need to pass? My moto is whatever no. of documents, they should download via thread. Please give me solution

Comment: @RohanPatel: One that you create yourself, with whatever queue and thread pool that you want.

Comment: If you need to download any file on tap list item, what will be your approach to achieve it?

Comment: @RohanPatel: I would either use an `IntentService` or a regular `Service` with its own `ThreadPoolExecutor`. If the user queues up a lot of downloads, that work may need to proceed even after the user leaves the app's UI. Hence, a service will be important.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i would help me