# How many AsyncTask executeOnExecutors can I run simultaneously on Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

How many AsyncTask executeOnExecutors can I run simultaneously on Android?

It seems like a lot of executeOnExecutors aren't running at the same time.
Is there a fixed number?

Comment: Please checkout this answer which will basically provide all information you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43115937/1231245

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of how many tasks can be run simultaneously. Since `AsyncTask` uses a thread pool executor with limited max number of worker threads (128) and the delayed tasks queue has fixed size 10, if you try to execute more than 138 your custom tasks the app will crash with `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException.`

Starting from 3.0 the API allows to use your custom thread pool executor via AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(Executor exec, Params... params) method. This allows, for instance, to configure the size of the delayed tasks queue if default 10 is not what you need.

As @Knossos mentions, there is an option to use AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel(task, params); from support v.4 library to run tasks in parallel without bothering with API level. This method became deprecated in API level 26.0.0.

Comment: Checkout this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible